# NP Lemma and rejection region having the size.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

quick question.

I need to find the rejection region of H_0, meaning that I need to find the constant value for which if X=x belongs to the region H_0 is rejected.

The pdf is c(1-x)^(c-1) with x belonging to (0,1) , the size of the test is 0.1 and under H_0: c=2, H_1: c=3.

Solving with the NPL formula I get:   $x> 1-(2/3)k$

How do I find the value of k?

I tried integrating the pdf on the interval 0 to $1-(2/3)k$ and equating to the size 0.1, but I seems to get it wrong.

Am I doing silly calculation mistakes? How should I find k ( and so the rejection region ):

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Are you sure about the rejection region? How do you get $x> 1-(2/3)k$?

Comment: I actually got x> 0.0513, which is in line with one of the choices, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: By calculating the CDF from 0 to 1-(2/3)k = to 0.1

Comment: If you are finding a most powerful test, you ought to reject $H_0$ for large values of the ratio $f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$ where $f$ is the pdf.

Comment: I need to find the interval for which I reject H_0

Comment: I am asking if you followed this method or not.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ has a $\mathsf{Beta}(1,c)$ distribution, so you can verify that $1-X\sim \mathsf{Beta}(c,1)$ and hence $$-c\ln(1-X)\sim \mathsf{Exp}(1)\,.$$

By NP lemma, a most powerful test for testing $H_0:c=2$ versus $H_1:c=3$ rejects $H_0$ for large values of the likelihood ratio $r(x)=f_{H_1}(x)/f_{H_0}(x)$ where $f(\cdot)$ is the pdf of $X$.

Now $r(x)=\frac32(1-x)$ for $x\in(0,1)$, hence we reject $H_0$ if $1-X>k$ for some constant $k\in(0,1)$. Size of the test is $0.1$, which means

$$P_{H_0}(1-X>k)=P_{H_0}(-2\ln(1-X)<-2\ln k)=0.1$$

That is, $$\int_0^{-2\ln k}e^{-x}\,dx=1-e^{2\ln k}=0.1$$

Solving for $k$ you get the rejection region $\{X:X<1-k\}$.